# What does "Not Enough Raw Materials" mean, and how do I fix it?

Tags: cities-skylines

What does "Not Enough Raw Materials" mean, and how do I fix it?  I can't get oil either.

Comment: That wouldn't mean the oil/wood is over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you don't have any direct control of what you import into your city. However, you can create more points of import by [building Cargo Terminals for trains and Cargo Harbours for boats.](https://skylines.paradoxwikis.com/Supply_chain#Imports_and_exports) Just make sure the train stations are connected to tracks going to the outside world. You can also increase your cities own production by building industrial sectors. Use the [oil specialization](https://skylines.paradoxwikis.com/Industrial_specialization#Oil) to get more oil if there's any on your map.